# How do I adapt this code to populate the address by geolocation when user lands on page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am looking to populate my address fields when the user accepts geolocation. And then use the search address as an override? At the moment the auto complete works fine and populates all the fields I need.

How do I / is it possible to adapt this JS to populate the fields via geo location.

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;
var pos;
var currentLocation;
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var place;

//The variables you want to recieve from Google
//when the address is selected
var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'long_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_2: 'long_name',
    postal_town: 'long_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initMap() {

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    //Finds your current location and displays it on the map
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) {
                pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng);
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: currentLocation,
                    zoom: 15
                });
             

            },
            function() {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }

        );
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
//Calls function that autocompletes form
    initAutocomplete();
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(
        browserHasGeolocation
            ? "Error: The Geolocation service failed."
            : "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation."
    );
    infoWindow.open(map);
}

function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
    // geographical location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {types: ['geocode']});

    // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
    // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
    autocomplete.setFields(['address_component', 'geometry']);


    // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
    // address fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details,
    // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }

    lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
    document.getElementById('address_latitude').value = lat;
    document.getElementById('address_longitude').value = lng;

    //Map zooms in to the location given
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: +lat, lng: +lng},
        zoom: 15
    });

    //Map marker is created and displays address
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: {lat: +lat, lng: +lng}
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.setContent(document.getElementById('autocomplete').value);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle(
                {center: geolocation, radius: position.coords.accuracy});
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: infoWindow is not defined` (because it isn't, javascript is case sensitive, `infoWindow` is not the same as `infowindow `

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, including any required HTML/CSS.

Comment: Is your site loaded over HTTPS? (does geolocation work)?

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip I edited it with the infoWindow error and now have it working. I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of trial and error I have this working with the following solution:

```
function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow, lat, lng) {

    var latitude = lat;
    var longitude = lng;
    const latlng = {
        lat: latitude,
        lng: longitude
    };
    geocoder.geocode({ location: latlng }, (results, status) => {
        if (status === "OK") {
        if (results[0]) {
            map.setZoom(11);
            const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });
            infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = results[0].address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    var val = results[0].address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                }
            }

        } else {
            window.alert("No results found");
        }
    } else {
        window.alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
    }
});
}
```

I then added to the initMap

```
const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow, lat, lng);
```

This might not be the best solution but it works.